# Population of people who speak African languages based on their population growth

Tags: african-languages

Will African languages grow very much along with their population?

For example, if Kikongo has 6.5 million speakers in 2020, will there be 25 million speakers of Kikongo by 2050?

Comment: How is anyone supposed to answer that? Nobody knows what will happen in 25 years…

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Well, there might be historical trends that have been observed  with other languages and communities. How would someone not familiar with languages know? And User6726 seems to have given it a good show.

Comment: @Araucaria-him Trends, yes, but even such trends are nearly all localised. Aside from statements that may be almost certain but are also very obvious (e.g., the world’s major lingua franca, English, will have more speakers, while moribund Mlabri will have fewer), we might be able to make educated guesses about specific languages in specific areas based on trends within those same languages, but a sweeping question about ‘African languages’ and ‘their population’ in general is way too broad and superficial to be answerable by anything more than guesswork.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet But to the extent that it’s true, you can say that just because you know more about the subject than OP!

Comment: Unless someone's native language is banned (such as by some crazy dictator) , one would have to **logically assume** that the ethnic population numbers reflect the number of native speakers for a particular language.

Comment: @Lambie That would give us hundreds of thousands of ethinicities with only a few hundred members.

Comment: @Araucaria-him So what? I assume that whatever the number of Kikongo speakers there are, those numbers would rise as that population rises.  I mean...

Comment: @Lambie What does that have to do with ethnicity? Should English and French speaking Canadians be regarded as being of different ethnicities on the basis that they speak different languages?  "**logically**"?

Comment: @Araucaria-him I try my best to avoid discussions about English- and French-speaking Canadians as it much too fraught. That said, for me, French Canadian is not an ethnicity. However, let's take, say, Brazil and Portugal. Will the numbers of Portuguese speakers increase as those populations increase? And where does the word ethicity arise here in this question? (Fyi, I am a French<>English interpreter. And my French is mainland France **and I have absolutely nothing against French Canadians, or any other type of French (West African, New Caledonian, Belgian, Swiss, etc.)**.

Answer (score 0):

No, for various reasons. First, you overestimate population expansion over 30 years, but we can remedy that by simply saying "proportionally more". Second, your particular choice is "in the middle". The number of Lingala speakers will expand substantially, the number of Zande speakers will plummet. The number of Kongo speakers will decline, but not as precipitously as the number of Ngbinda, which may be extinct in another generation or two. In Kenya for example all languages other than Swahili and English will decline somewhat, some more than others (Boni (Aweer) and Suba for instance are being replaced with Swahili and Luo).

Comment: I fail to see how you can predict all this. Sounds crazy to me.